# Golang JSON Date time.Date() Testing Request

Tags: json, go

I am working on Golang creating API. I have a route [PUT]: /accounts/{id}.

```
{
    "firstName": "MakeUPDATED",
    "lastName": "FakeUPDATED",
    "birthday": "2000-12-31 14:30:15",
    "phoneNumber": "98423423"
}
```

I am sending this as a request body. But in code it can not convert date to time.Time type.

```
type UpdateAccountRequest struct {
FirstName   string    `json:"firstName"`
LastName    string    `json:"lastName"`
Birthday    time.Time `json:"birthday"`
PhoneNumber string    `json:"phoneNumber"` }
```

And the test:

```
updateAccReq := new(models.UpdateAccountRequest)
if err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&updateAccReq); err != nil {
    functionalities.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, APIServerError{Error: "invalid request body: "+err.Error()})
    return
}
```

I get:

```
{ "error": "invalid request body: parsing time \"2000-12-31 14:30:15\" as \"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\": cannot parse \" 14:30:15\" as \"T\"" }
```

*I would to be able to test with JSON request just on Postman. How can I solve that?*

Comment: Unmarshal birthday as string and parse to a time afterwards with appropriate format. Maybe by letting UpdateAccountRequest implement json.Unmarshaler.

Comment: The format you send does notmatch the expected format (With 'T* separating the date and the time part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, JSON uses [`time.Time.UnmarshalJSON`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.UnmarshalJSON) which requires [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339.html) which is basically [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This is `<date>T<time>` or `2000-12-31T14:30:15`.

You either need to change what you expect as a timestamp, or implement your own [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler).

Comment: Nice, thanks.

I found one more way to solve with time.Parse().

Comment: @srmback Your alternative solution would be useful to others. Would you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As a problem was a time.Time type, I used time.Parse() with layout. So it converted my "panicky" string to time.Time.
Here you go:

```
var birthday time.Time
    if createAccReq.Birthday != "" {
        var parseErr error
        birthday, parseErr = time.Parse("2006-01-02", createAccReq.Birthday)
        if parseErr != nil {
            return
        }
    }

// time.Parse(LAYOUT, DECODED_VAL)
```